# need an associative array from two mysql colums

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

i have a mysql table

```
||==========||==========||==========||
||    id    ||   name   ||   age    ||
||==========||==========||==========||
||    1     ||   joe    ||   10     ||
||    2     ||   harry  ||   20     ||
||    3     ||   jane   ||   45     ||
||    4     ||   john   ||   56     ||
||    5     ||   larry  ||   89     ||
||    6     ||   henry  ||   23     ||
||    7     ||   steve  ||   25     ||
||    8     ||   eric   ||   56     ||
||    9     ||   dave   ||   98     ||
||    10    ||   mat    ||   56     ||
||==========||==========||==========||
```

i need the sql query that would make an associative array from this table and give me values like this

```
id=>age
1=>10
4=>56
```

i also need to make all the id's as a variable where there value would be the age like

```
$1 = 10
$4 = 56
```

or if i could add a prefix to the variables

```
$id_1 = 10
$id_4 = 56
```

thanks in advance

Comment: i think their is no direct approach to generate the array like this, first fetch the records and store the result to array like you need.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` takes the result of a query, and returns one row as an associative array.  Call it repeatedly to get all rows.

Answer (score 0):

if your using php for fetching your data you may use the function mysql_fetch_array example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
{
echo $row['name'].'<br>';
}
```

you may know more about mysql functions for php on this site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = '1, 4';
$sql = "select age from __TABLE__ where id in ( {$ids} )";

$link = mysql_connect('__SERVER__', '__DBUSER__', '__DB_PWD__') or die('connect error');
$db = mysql_select_db('__DBNAME__', $link) or die('db error');

$rs = mysql_query($sql, $link);

$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    $result[] = $row;
}
extract(my_result($result));
var_dump($id_1);
var_dump($id_4);
function my_result($result, $prefix = 'id_')
{
    $data = array();
    foreach($result as $k => $v)
    {
        $data[$prefix . $v['id']] = $v['order_no'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```